# How can I type to see only one row in df.head()

Tags: python

For example, if I want to see only one sentence in the dataframe in row 21, how can I type in the head function?
df.head(20)? df.head(19:20)

Comment: use `df.iloc[20:21, :]`

Comment: It might be worth your time to have a look through the really excellent [Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) section of the pandas user guide

Answer (score 0):

you can access elements with their integer position `df.iat[row,col]`
or an integer row with `df.iloc([row])`